# Como utilizar pasta para armazenar imagens em um projeto Web Api publicado no Windows Azure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, microsoft-azure

Tenho uma pasta criada na raiz de um projeto `Web Api` chamada `Images`. Em `localhost` gravo elas da seguinte forma:

```
 File.WriteAllBytes(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images/") + image.Name, image.Image);
```

Para exibir as imagens em `localhost` eu só preciso do endereço da mesma. Sendo assim, no controller eu crio uma ViewBag que recebe o endereço da imagem(Ex.: `http://localhost:49730/Images/Product1.jpg`) e com esse código eu posso exibir ela:

```
<a href="@ViewBag.Image">Abrir Imagem</a>
```

Depois de ter publicado no `Windows Azure` ao salvar a imagem a mesma não está sendo recuperada apartir da url.

O que precisa ser feito diferente do `localhost` para funcionar no `Windows Azure`?

Atualização: antes de publicar no windows azure eu publiquei o endereço do azure no lugar do localhost, os outros serviços funcionam normalmente, só essa as imagens que não estão sendo salvas/recuperadas.

Answer (score 3):

Na sua `ViewBag.Image` faça assim:

```
/Images/Product1.jpg
```

Ou seja retirei o endereço `http://localhost:49730`, não tem precisão, ai se no seu Windows Azure a pasta fizer a mesma correspondência não precisa fazer nenhuma alteração no servidor, ficando assim padrão tanto no `localhost` quanto no `Web Windows Azure`

Comment: Se eu fizer assim ele pega o endereço atual + o "/Images/Product1.jpg", a questão é que eu estou acessando apartir de outro projeto, então eu add sempre o endereço do localhost do web api(que é diferente do localhost do meu asp.net mvc 5), e claro, antes de publicar no windows azure eu publiquei o endereço do azure no lugar do localhost, os outros serviços funcionam normalmente, só essa as imagens que não estão sendo salvar/recuperadas. Será que é preciso colocar essa pasta em um diretório que existe para esse tipo de situação?

Comment: Olha eu imaginei que a pasta estava no servidor com as imagens!!! É assim que poderia fazer na minha opinião...

Answer (score 1):

Como Arquiteto de Software, gostaria de compartilhar.

> Não se hospeda arquivos em servidores de aplicação

Isso é uma péssima prática, e deve ser evitada ao extremo.

Existem serviços específicos para persistência de massa de dados, como arquivos de imagens, documentos office, entre outros: [Blob Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/services/storage/).

Nele é que deve ser feito o armazenamento de arquivos. Ele dá super suporte para gravar com segurança e baixo custo, backups simplificados, recursos para acesso externo para download e rápida recuperação.

Fora o preço:

- WebAPI: R$ 45 / GB / mês
- Azure Blob Storage: R$ 0,12 / GB / mês

WepAPI é apenas para responder requisições HTTP. Persistência, deixe para o Blob Storage.